# Event data target dataset key returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a filter where i sort data by date and answers, at first i was only filtering by date so i was using **data.target.value** and it was workin, since i have added the answers sorting i had to use the dataset, after doing this the data.target.dataset.dir & data.target.dataset.sort returns undefined

In a child component i have a select, **SelectField** renders the select with styled component :

```
<SelectField 
    onChange={props.triCallback}
>
    <option data-sort="date" data-dir="desc">Filter by</option>
    <option data-sort="date" data-dir="asc">Date asc</option>
    <option data-sort="date" data-dir="desc">Date desc</option>
    <option data-sort="answers" data-dir="asc">Answers asc</option>
    <option data-sort="answers" data-dir="desc">Answers Desc</option>
</SelectField>
```

And in my App.js i have this method which handles the sorting :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sorting : 'date',
      sortDir : 'desc',
    };
}

onTriChanged = data => {
    const sorting = data.target.dataset.sort;
    const sortDir = data.target.dataset.dir;
    this.setState({
      sortDir: sortDir,
      sorting: sorting
    }, () => {
        this.fetchData()
    });
};
```

Comment: Does `<SelectField>` render a `<select>` element?

Comment: @Terry yes it's a select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `<SelectField>` actually renders a native `<select>` underneath, then it is pretty straight-forward. The reason why `data.target.dataset...` returns undefined is because those HTML5 `data-` attributes that you want to retrieve actually reside on the selected `<option>` element and not the `<select>` element, the latter of which is referenced by `data.target`.

Therefore, you will need to access the selection `<option>` element, using the [`selectedIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex). The `<select>` element allows us to access the nested collection of `<option>` elements via the [`options` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/options).

```
onTriChanged = data => {
    const selectedOption = data.target.options[data.target.selectedIndex];
    const sorting = selectedOption.dataset.sort;
    const sortDir = selectedOption.dataset.dir;
    this.setState({
      sortDir: sortDir,
      sorting: sorting
    }, () => {
        this.fetchData()
    });
};
```

Comment: this return an error 'selectedIndex' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @Elichy Fixed a typo, forgot that it should be `data.target.selectedIndex`